# Undo/Redo functionality in CamanJS?

Tags: camanjs

Hi Im a newbie in camanjs.

I manipulate canvas with this code.

```
        function vintage(id){
    Caman(id, function(){

    //I just added this code to reset the canvas to its original state
    this.revert();
    //----------------------------

    this.vintage();
    this.render();

    });
    }
```

With the code *this.revert();* , I can turn the canvas back to its original state.
What if I use multiple effects and presets and just I want to revert the canvas few steps back to my last used effect?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to do that, but you can stash the canvas in a hidden span, and then replace it as part of an undo chain.

use clone to stash it